# Flink Savepoint and Window Operation

Tags: apache-flink

Below is a sample Flink code that I have used to test checkpoint/save point.

```
DataStream<Alarm> complexAlarmStream = alarmStream.keyBy(Alarm::getOntId)
.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(config                        .get(CheckPointTestingHighlevelFunctionParams.ONT_POWEROFF_DETECTION_WINDOW_TIME_IN_MIN))))
.process(new CheckPointTestingHighlevelFunction())
.uid("CheckPointTestingFunction").name("CheckPointTestingFunction");
```

Here the window is a stateful operation that holds the data for the amount of time mentioned in  `CheckPointTestingHighlevelFunctionParams.ONT_POWEROFF_DETECTION_WINDOW_TIME_IN_MIN`

How to give a UID for the window function.

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared is setting a UID for the window operator. When you specify

```java
.keyBy(...)
.window(...)
.allowedLateness(...)
.sideOutputLateData(...)
.process(...)
.uid("window-id").name("window-id")
```

all of that is contributing to the specification of the window operator.